# Как преименовывать изображение  при загрузке типа 00001?

Tags: php

`$filename = 00001;` - подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Comment: @Bridun, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: вопрос не решен

Answer (score 1):

В таком виде: `$filename = 00001;` в переменную запишется число `1`, а не строка с нулями. Поэтому, если на вход даётся именно число, а надо «добить» его нулями до нужной длины, можно так, используя форматированный вывод [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
$n = 22;
$filename = sprintf( '%05d', $n); // добивает целое число до 5 позиций нулями
```

А потом [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php):

```
move_uploaded_file( $tmpfilename, $filename);
```

---

В связи с комментарием, оказывается, другую задачу решали.

Надо получить сначала наибольший существующий "номер" файла в папке.

```
$dirName = '/path/to/files';
if (FALSE === ($handle = opendir( $dirName))) exit("Не открыть директорию");
$maxFile = 0;
while (FALSE !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if( !preg_match('/\d+\..+$/', $entry, $matches) continue; // нужно, чтобы имя попадало в паттерн  цифры-точка-ещёбуквы-конецстроки
    $maxFile = max( $maxFile, (int)$matches[1]);
}
closedir($handle);
// в $maxFile теперь записано макс. значение из папки

$filename = sprintf( '%05d', ++$maxFile);
// вам ещё нужно продумать, как приписать файлу правильное расширение, 
// иначе будут просто  00123
// при этом хорошо бы проверять содержимое файлов, а не доверять тому, что прислал пользователь
// напр. могут загрузить php файл, названный "trollface.jpg.php"
move_uploaded_file( $tmpfilename, $filename); // эту строку надо исправить!
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но вопрос в следующем: как при загрузке переименовывать рисунки или файлы с отчетом 00001, а когда загрузится второй, должно быть 0002, в конечном счете типа 566778.jpg, как-то так.

Comment: $file_name = strval( $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'] + sprintf( '%05d', ++$maxFile) );

пробую так перезаписывает но не добавляет

Comment: `+` складывает как числа, это не то, что вам нужно!

Comment: @Sergiks А почему не воспользоваться итератором:

[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/gv4fFEsC)

    $dirUpload = '/path/to/';
    $recurcive = false;
    
    $count = (new FileManager)->count($dirUpload, $recurcive);
    $filename = sprintf('%05d',  ++$count);
    
    move_uploaded_file($tmpfilename, $filename);

@Bridun Кроме того, необходимо позаботиться о максимальном количестве файлов в директории. При большом количестве поиск может существенно замедлиться. Потому:

    $maxFiles = 1000;
    $filename = '/' . floor($count / $maxFiles) . '/' . sprintf('%05d',  ++$count);

Comment: @Bridun В целях оптимизации $count можно хранить в key-value strorage (memcached, redis,..) и при добавлении инкрементировать его.

Вот Вам в помощь [библиотека](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem), которая всё это умеет (осуществлять поиск файлов и кэширует файловую структуру с учётом изменений), кроме `move_uploaded_file`. По upload, можете сами попробовать написать с обязательной валидацией, либо вновь обратиться к github.

Comment: Спасибо за совет поработаю

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.su/rename