# Как при создании файла задавать ему имя типа 00001 и записи в файл, чтоб создавалась 00001?

Tags: php

```
<? 
        $d = dir ("content/");
        while (false !== ($entry = $d->read()))
        {
            if (preg_match("/[0-9].dat/", $entry)){
                $nums[] = str_replace (".dat", "", $entry);
            }
        }
        if(!isset($nums)){
            $n = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            sort ($nums);
            $n = $nums[count($nums)-1] + 1;
        }
```

Создается файл с именем 0 1 2 с отсчетом от 0 1 2 и т.д.

Как отсчет делать 0000001 при создании файла и т.д., подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
<?
        $file = file("news.dat");
        $max = 0;
        foreach( $file as $line)
        {   
            if ( !empty($line) )
            {   
                $elem = explode("<!>",$line);
                if ( $elem[0] > $max) $max = $elem[0];  
            }
        }
        $max++;
```

// вычисляем номер последней записи в файле 0 1 2 и т.д.

Как делать отсчет в записи  00001 00002, а не 0  1 2?

Comment: Вопрос не понятен, код нечитаем. Отформатируйте, пожалуйста, код. И сформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы был понятен не только вам.

Comment: Простой способ привести `1` к строке `"000001"`:

    $i = 1;
    $s = substr("00000".$i, -6);

Answer (score 1):

Зачем Вам ведущие нули в названии файла?

Имя файла можно получить

```
$basename = basename('/path/to/00002.dat'); //result: 00002.dat
```

Далее можно воспользоваться магией динамической типизации:

```
var_dump((int)$basename); //result: 2
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Что вас смущает в такой иерархии:

[image]

> ну некрасиво, если отсчитывать 1 2 3 и т.д

В программировании нет такого выражения "красиво/некрасиво" - должно быть быстро и надёжно.

Такая форма `00001` записи усложняет функционал. Если в этом нет необходимости, нужно делать проще.

Я Вам писал в комментариях [к предыдущему вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/391495/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-00001), как проще сделать. Повторюсь:

Берем класс с итератором [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Q9C7fJep). Далее

```
$dirUpload = '/path/to/';
$recurcive = false;
$maxFiles = 1000;
$tmpfilename = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$filename = md5_file($tmpfilename);

$fileManager = new FileManager;
$count = $fileManager->count($dirUpload, $recurcive);

$filename = '/' . floor($count / $maxFiles) . '/' . $filename;

move_uploaded_file($tmpfilename, $filename);
```

В целях оптимизации, `$count` можно хранить в key-value strorage (memcached, redis,..) и при добавлении инкрементировать его.

Вот Вам в помощь [библиотека](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem), которая всё это умеет (осуществлять поиск файлов и кэширует файловую структуру с учётом изменений), кроме `move_uploaded_file`. По upload, можете сами попробовать написать с обязательной валидацией, либо вновь обратиться к github.

Comment: не ведущие нули, вы неправильно поняли, это должна создаваться дериктория, в ней файлы, их будет много, ну некрасиво, если отсчитывать 1 2 3 и т.д. до 10000, а если отсчитывать 000001 и до  10000, ну типа так и, сответствено, записать в файл как регистрация об дериктории.

Comment: это должно быть ка id регистрации

Comment: id : 1 или id : 000001

Comment: @Bridun Дополнил ответ

Comment: $count = (new FileManager)->count($dirUpload, $recurcive);

в этом месте count ошибка помогите исправить

Comment: @Bridun я вам привёл ссылку на [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Q9C7fJep), где, собственно, размещён класс `FileManager` (скопируйте его себе в проект).
Да, кстати, возможно у Вас PHP < 5.4.
Потому,

   $fileManager = new FileManager;
   $count = $fileManager->count($dirUpload, $recurcive);

Исправил [ответ](http://hashcode.ru/questions/391497#391533).